# Why module included outside the class adds instance methods to class's objects

Tags: ruby

I am experimenting with the Ruby `include` keyword as shown below:

```
module A
    def show
    puts "working"
    end
end

include A

class E
end

class D
end

e = E.new
d = D.new
e.show
d.show

o = Object.new
puts o.respond_to?("show")

******************************output****************

working
working
true
```

I was expecting output to be `undefined method` but it's giving me the proper output. I have also observed that the `show` method defined in `module A` is becoming an instance method of `Object`.

Why are these methods becoming instance methods of the class `Object`?
Please help in understanding this concept.

Comment: Worth reading: [What is the Ruby Top-Level?](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because instances of class [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Class.html) inherit from [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html).

Thus, modules, included into `Object` are available to instances of `Class`'s instances (instances of your `E` and `D` classes).

```
class A
end

module B
  def test; :hi end
end
#=> test

include B
#=> Object

A.new.test
#=> :hi

Object.new.test
#=> :hi
```

Having `include B` written in the top-level means `include`'ing `B` into `Object`.

`include B` is the outermost context is equivalent to:

```
class Object
  include B
end
```

The only class, whose instances do not share module `B`'s methods is [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html).

Comment: Due to this behaviour you could call `show` on anything, even a number `5.show`

Comment: but i have not included module "A" inside "Object" class ??

Comment: @sanjay including in the outermost scope means `include`'ing into `Object` :)

Comment: does it mean that include A is equal to class Object include A end;

Comment: @sanjay absolutely

Comment: Ok then I have defined show method outside the class as def show end; and trying to call it with object of Object class but it is giving me error as "private method `show' called for #<Object:0x00000001633db8>" why ?? calling it directly works . why ??

Comment: @sanjay it depends on Ruby version, I remember it was changing over time, that methods defined in the `Object`s scope were private. In my 2.3.0 method `test` is public, you can see in the updated answer

Comment: No, methods defined at the top-level are private in Ruby. They are, however, public in IRb. This is one of the ways in which IRb differs from Ruby. Some other differences are corner cases in local variable handling, and some syntax that is legal in Ruby but rejected by IRb. Moral of the story: don't use IRb to verify Ruby behavior.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ooh, right-right, thanks for clarification, i forgot it was irb's thing, not related to Ruby version.